# How to draw a closed smooth curve from a list of nodes?

Tags: pstricks

[image]

`Karl` is a list of randomly generated nodes by `\curvepnodes` using parametric points in RPN (I don't know how to use `rand` in algebraic expression). The number of elements of the list is `\Karlnodecount + 1` or `plotpoints`.

In the documentation, I only see `\psnline` to connect the list with a straight line segment between two consecutive nodes. To close the path, I invoke `\closepath` inside `\pscustom`.

- Unfortunately, the closing line segment does not look smooth.
- Instead of using a straight line segment, I want to use a curved one. Using `\psparametricplot[plotstyle=curve]` does help a bit but the closing segment is still problematic.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}
\psset
{
    fillstyle=solid,
    fillcolor=gray,
    linearc=2pt,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\curvepnodes[plotpoints=40]{0}{360}{/R rand 1001 mod 1000 div 1.5 add def R t cos mul  R t sin mul}{Karl}
\pscustom
{
    \psnline(0,\Karlnodecount){Karl}
    \closepath
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I also tried using `\multido` and `\curveto` but `\curveto` needs 3 points per invocation (two of them are control points of a bezier curve).

How to draw a closed smooth curve from a list of nodes?

Comment: Does it have to be pstricks? I'm sure you can do this with tikz.

Comment: @Anke: The bounties are offered for a single correct answer in PSTricks. I am so sorry. Solutions in TikZ are welcome but there is no bounty for them.

Comment: It's ok, I'm no bounty hunter ;) If it was just about getting the desired result, I could have helped. But if this is just about proving a point or whatever, I'm not going to bother trying to help with tikz.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node,multido}
\SpecialCoor
\pstVerb{1234 srand} 
\def\PlotImage#1{% #1: no of points
  \pstVerb{ /Step 360 #1 div def } \def\randompath{}
  \multido{\i=0+1}{#1}{%
    \xdef\randompath{\randompath(! Rand 2 mul 1 sub 2.5 add \i\space Step mul PtoC  )}}%
  \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psset{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black!20}
    \expandafter\psccurve\randompath
    \psset{linecolor=red,opacity=0.4,fillcolor=blue!40}
    \expandafter\psccurve\randompath
  \end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}

\PlotImage{36}  \PlotImage{142}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When the number of points is, say, `142`, the result looks strange.

Comment: @g.kov: `\curvepnodes` makes life easier because we don't need to calculate the angle step.

Comment: @g.kov: see my edit, the no of plotpoints is now no problem.

Comment: @Herbert: Yes, now it's perfect.

Comment: `1 sub 2.5 add`?

Comment: Sorry. As you have implemented `\psnccurve`, you probably want to update your question to make the code much simpler.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry, I don't know PSTricks, but for comparison, this is the Metapost equivalent of Jake's TikZ solution:

[image]

```
\starttext

\startMPpage[offset=3mm]

  path p;
  p := for i = 0 step 10 until 350 : (1 randomized 1)*dir(i) .. endfor cycle;
  draw p scaled 1cm;

\stopMPpage


\stoptext
```

Comment: Ha, wow, Metapost is succinct! +1

Comment: @Jake: Yes, after all, metapost follows the syntax of metafont, a language designed by Knuth: succinct, precise, and weird (in the same way as TeX is weird).

Answer (score 10):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetseed{2}
\edef\randompath{}
\foreach \theta in {0,10,...,350} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\r{rnd+1}
    \xdef\randompath{\randompath (\theta:\r) ..}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
\expandafter\draw\randompath cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not PSTricks, but it's a wonderful example of how elegant PGF/TikZ can be. +1.

Comment: There is a special bounty of 250 for your `\xdef` technique. I will be given at the last in your answer in another question (not this question because the fifth bounty cannot be 250).

Comment: That reminds me ... I must upload the latest version of hobby to CTAN.  Then it becomes a smidgeon easier: `\draw[use Hobby shortcut] ([closed]0:rnd+2) \foreach \ang in
{0,10,...,350} { .. (\ang:rnd+2) };`

Comment: I get `Use of \tikz@curveto@double doesn't match its definition.`. I have a recent version of hobby. The problem seems to come from `cycle`

Comment: @AlainMatthes Didn't spot that comment.  I messed around with the internals of the package and broke the `cycle` syntax (I think irreparably).  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121310/86 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The bullet proof solution.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\psset{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray}

\def\points{}
\pstVerb{realtime srand}
\def\N{25}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\curvepnodes[plotpoints=\N]{0}{360}{rand 16 mod 15 div 1.5 add t PtoC}{P}
\multido{\i=0+1}{\Pnodecount}{\xdef\points{\points (P\i)}}
\expandafter\psccurve\points
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\psnccurve` to save more keystrokes!